# Scala for loop to calculate sum of powers

Tags: scala

I am very new to Scala and am trying to create a loop that will calculate the sum of powers `(1^1 + 2^2 + ... + 10^10)` without using an exponent operator.

I discovered that `1^1` through `9^9` calculate correctly. But for some reason `10^10` evaluates to `1410065409` in my current code and messes up my final output of the sum. What is causing this mathematical error?

My current code is:

```
var i = 1 
var ex = 1
var sum = 0 

while (i <= 10) 
{
   for (j <- 1 to i) 
   {
      ex = ex * i 
   }

   sum += ex
   ex = 1
   i += 1
}

println(s"The sum is $sum")
```

Comment: `10^10` overflows an `Int`. To go that high you need to be working with `Long` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it's done in Scala.

```
List.tabulate(10)(n => List.fill(n+1)(n.toLong+1).product).sum
//res0: Long = 10405071317
```

Comment: You could juts use `math.pow` instead of the `List.fill.product` Also, since you are going to `sum` everything I would use an **Iterator** instead of a **List** for the `tabulate`

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguel. I interpreted the OP's desire to do it _"without using an exponent operator"_ to mean without `pow()`, which certainly would be more direct. As for `Iterator`, I agree, but `List` is shorter and it's already a rather long line of code. (I should have used `(1 to 10).map(...`. Then I wouldn't have to bother with the `fill()` adjustments.)

Comment: _"without using an exponent operator"_ oh sorry, I skip that part when reading the question, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you have, is to use `Math.pow`:

```
val result1 = 1.to(10).map(x => Math.pow(x, x)).sum
```

Please note that `result1` is of type `Double`, and has the value `1.0405071317E10`.

If you want to have it as long, you can do:

```
val result2 = 1.to(10).map(x => Math.pow(x, x).toLong).sum
```

Then `result2` will have the value `10405071317`.